# Jquery have to double click to submit form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a form that will only submit, if I double click the submit button. Also if i do not unbind('submit'), then it does not fire at all. Any ideas what i need to change so that it requires just one click. Thanks in advance.

```
$('#formID').submit(function (event) 
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var InspectionDate = $('#datepicker').val().split('/');
    InspectionDate.reverse();
    InspectionDate = InspectionDate.join('-');
    InspectionHour = $('#time_hour').val();
    InspectionMinutes = $('#time_minutes').val();
    var InspectionDateTime = InspectionDate + ' ' + InspectionHour + ':' + InspectionMinutes + ':00';
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_booking_check.php",
        data: 'InspectionDateTime=' + InspectionDateTime,
        cache: false,
        success: function (response) 
        {
            if (response == 1) 
            {
                alert("An appointment for the selected Date and Time already exists.\n\nDouble Bookings are not possible.\n\nPlease refer to the calender to find an available appointment.");
            } 
            else 
            {
                $('#formID').unbind('submit').submit();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: you are preventing the default action right at the top. event.preventDefault();

Comment: Yes he does so that the submitting goes via ajax. That shouldn't be it

Comment: @Matt - I need the event.preventDefault() otherwise the form submits regardless of the response from the AJAX request. I was just wondering if there was another way of submitting the form in the else section of the response, that would only require one click of the submit button.

Comment: the `unbind` will cause default browser submit on second clcik. Sounds like your ajax isn't connecting properly. Inspect AJAX request in browser console. Check status, response (if any), data sent etc.

Comment: Put some kind of debug message by the AJAX function - is your code reaching it on the first click?

Comment: @charlietfl from the description he's given, it sounds like the AJAX works. I'm pretty sure the problem is that the `.submit()` at the end is failing or getting blocked for some reason, but I haven't seen the actual problem yet...

Comment: Check for any errors before the ajax execution. In `$.ajax` use the `error` callback, too: http://www.unseenrevolution.com/jquery-ajax-error-handling-function/

Comment: @Dave not sure how you came to that conclusion if first clcik doesn't work, and only way form is submitting is though browser default submittal

Comment: @charlietfl because it (supposedly) *does* work on the second click, which means the handler must be getting removed. But all I can think of is that `.unbind` should be `.off`.

Comment: just checked through the web console, the ajax request are going through and return a result. as @Dave said, the problem is the .submit() within the else block at the end of the code. If i just have $('#formID').submit() then it does nothing. add the .unbind to it, and it works but only on double clicking submit.

Comment: @Dave - just tried changing .unbind to .off and the same result

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle of this and it works as it should: http://jsfiddle.net/ujWSj/ Are you sure it isn't getting bound multiple times or being affected by some other external factor?

Comment: @Dave - Just looked at the jsfiddle, your right it works they way you have done it, but I do not want to submit if the ajax returns success. I do an IF statement on the response to determine if it should be submitted, and it's within the If and Else statements that it goes wrong. I can not think of any external factors, nothing else is involved with this script, apart from the php file referenced in the AJAX request.

Comment: @BrianDavies That doesn't make sense; you say that it works on a second click, which means the `unbind` must be getting called, so we already know it goes down that branch. I just cut the code down because I didn't have a convenient resource for the script to actually load (cross-site-scripting and all that).

Comment: @Dave - the only thing that maybe influencing the script is a validation script running on the form fields. It is also within  `$(document).ready{}`. I cannot think of anything else.

Comment: @Dave - totally baffled. From what i can make out, the first click unbinds, then the second click is not effected by the submit function, and submits.

Comment: The validation could be the issue. Your `unbind` will be removing that validation function (you change this code to use a named function to make it remove only this one function). Can you post more code (preferably cut-down to the important stuff. Ideal if you can edit the fiddle I posted until it shows the problem then paste the new link)

Comment: @Dave - I have just posted the additional code into jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ujWSj/3/) so you can see whats, what!Thanks for your help BTW!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `validationEngine`, but I've had a quick look through its source code and I've played around with the fiddle you posted. Here's what I came up with (cut-down code):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ischecking=false;
    function mychecker(event) {
        if(event.isDefaultPrevented()){
            return false;
        }
        event.preventDefault();
        if(ischecking){
            return false;
        }
        ischecking=true;
        $.ajax({
            // ...
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                // ...
                $('#formID').off('submit',mychecker).submit();
            },
            complete: function(){
                ischecking=false;
            }
        });
    }
    jQuery('#formID').validationEngine().submit(mychecker);
});
```

Notice two changes:

1. I added a check to make sure the event hadn't already been cancelled by the validator, and to make sure it isn't already checking with the server;
2. I gave the function a name (`mychecker`) and removed it specifically instead of removing all bound events.

This code works, and fixes some things which needed fixing, but I can't say for sure that it will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but unfortunately it is still doing exactly the same thing.

Comment: Well, in that case the problem is in code which you haven't shared yet. Thoughts in no particular order: Do you get any errors or warnings displayed in the console? Which browser are you using? Does it submit OK if you replace `mychecker` with an empty function? Which version of jQuery are you using? (if below 1.9 then update!)

Comment: I am using Jquery 1.9.1, and there are no error warnings within the console. As for my code, all I have apart from the code already shown, is the HTML form and PHP to insert the data into an mysql DB. I am fairly certain that is correct, as it all works fine, it is just the ajax query on submit which is causing an issue. Maybe wrong... if you would like to see it, advise the best place to put it, as it is to long to post in here.